# How to downsample using r-caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'd like to downsample my data given that I have a signficant class imbalance. Without downsampling, my GBM model performs reasonably well; however, with r-caret's downSample, accuracy = 0.5. I applied the same downsampling to another GBM model and got exactly the same results. What gives?

```
set.seed(1914)
down_train_my_gbm <- downSample(x = combined_features, 
                                y = combined_features$label)
down_train_my_gbm$label <- NULL
my_gbm_combined_downsampled <- train(Class ~ ., 
                                     data = down_train_my_gbm, 
                                     method = "gbm",
                                     trControl = trainControl(method="repeatedcv", 
                                                 number=10, repeats=3,  
                                                 classProbs = TRUE),
                                     preProcess = c("range"),
                                     verbose = FALSE)
```

I suspected that the issue might have to do with classProbs=TRUE. Changing this to FALSE skyrockets the accuracy to >0.95...but I get the exact same results for multiple models (which do not result in the same accuracy without downsampling). I'm baffled by this. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't really subsample outside of resampling. It can result in [misleading estimates of performance](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html#resampling). 

Otherwise, it is hard to say without a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Caret train function allows to downsample, upsample and more with the trainControl options: from the guide [Subsampling During Resampling](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html#subsampling-during-resampling), in your case it would be

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     ## new option here:
                     sampling = "down")

model_with_down_sample <- train(Class ~ ., data = imbal_train,
                                method = "gbm",
                                preProcess = c("range"),
                                verbose = FALSE,
                                trControl = ctrl)
```

As a side note, avoid the formula style (e.g. Class~ .), but use the direct columns: it has been shown to have issues with memory and speed when many predictors are used (https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/263).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be aware that in the current version (6.0-86) caret will not resample the class with the lowest count, just re-use the same cases for every iteration. You might want to try a cross-validation method inside a bootstrap loop that actually resamples from each class.